What is the subtle error here in recreating the metallic effect with a specular BSDF?
I'm attempting to recreate the properties of the metallic workflow using the Specular BSDF shader, in order to be able to better control certain portions of it.
Here's what I have so far. The orbs on the left of each pair are the built-in Principled BSDF, while those on the right are the displayed nodes. The X-axis is metal, and the Y-axis is roughness. All other values are defaults.

The logic of the shader is simple: based on the metal input, mix the base colour towards black and the specular colour away from white. Using 0.04 instead of pure white for the starting specular colour comes from the docs, based on the default IOR of 1.5.
I'd say I'm close: two of the four corners look exactly the same between this shader and the PBSDF. But the other two are subtly wrong:

In the top-right corner, where metal = 1.0 and roughness = 1.0, the general colour of the shader is...I think it could be described as "less saturated", though it's hard to figure out if that's it exactly.
In the bottom-left corner, where metal = 0.0 and roughness = 0.0, the "rim darkening" effect is completely missing.

These are also affecting the rest of the interior examples, though it's less obvious further away from the problem corner. Any advice for fixing these inconsistencies, without messing up the rest?
EDIT: I have something now that's...well, a different try at least:

...but it still has problems:

no rim effect at all
the specularities are completely absent on the left side (where metal = 0.0)
uses a "glossy" shader instead of the "specular" shader (which...I'm not actually sure right now if that's a problem, but if it still allows control of the specular part separately from the diffuse part, maybe it's fine?)


Try switching the "Color" option to "Vector" on your Mix nodes perhaps? The color option might be applying some color space transform under the hood maybe. Just a guess.

@Jakemoyo nope,  ɓl blender cares about color space only when loading an image (concerts to linear) and when rendering/ saving

@MarkusvonBroady hmm, yeah that was just a shot in the dark

Okay part three.

I ended up doing both a glossy and a specular, adding the two together based on the metalness. I also got a decently-close approximation of the rim effect by doing a fresnel based on the square root of the roughness - it made the 0.75 and 0.5 cases more accurate than pure linear, but the 0.25 case less, so I guess the PBSDF uses some more clever function.
So while the rim isn't perfect and there's still some discolouration in the top-right corner, I think this is probably good enough for my use case.
